# Issue Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Optiplex 7080 - Disks Not Detected

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, ssd

I encountered a problem while attempting to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Optiplex 7080.
During the installation process, I received an installer error:

[installer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsE2z.png)

After rebooting the PC, I received the following message: "Block probing did not discover any disks. Unfortunately this means that installation will not be possible."

[hdd not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q7Vk.png)

Now, my M.2 SSD seems to have disappeared completely. BIOS does not detect any HDD (I've tried AHCI, RAID, disabled). When I attempted to use a USB adapter and plug it into a Windows machine, I received an "unrecognized USB device" error.

This problem occurred on three different machines, and now I have three unusable M.2 SSDs. I've tried using gparted and lsusb; neither can detect the disks.

I'm fairly certain the issue is with Ubuntu. On the third machine, I was able to successfully install Rocky 8.8 before trying (and failing) to install Ubuntu.

I used different ISOs for the latter two attempts: 20.04.05 for the first one, and 20.04.06 for the rest.

For creating the bootable USB, I used Rufus, and I've tried both MBR and GPT.

Interestingly, I was able to successfully install Ubuntu 20.04 on the same machines using old 64GB SSDs. I had to unplug the M.2 SSDs because, even though BIOS does not detect them, booting was significantly slowed.

Did Ubuntu somehow killed 3x m.2 ssd's?

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not expect, the installer to do firmware upgrades. Are your devices on this list: https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/

Comment: I can see Dell Optiplex 7080 twice on this list. I can't see the m.2 tho. All 3 are Transcend TS256GMTE710T